# Prove that $AB*CD+AD*BC\ge2*A(ABCD)$

Tags: geometry, inequality

Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral. Then prove $(AB\cdot CD+AD\cdot BC)\geq 2A(ABCD)$, where
$A(ABCD)$ means area of $ABCD$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or get closed. To prevent that, please [edit](http://goo.gl/mLWc8) the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $D'$ s.t. $|A-D|=|C-D'|,\ |C-D|=|A-D'|$ so that ${\rm area}\
ABCD = {\rm area}\ ABCD'$

Further \begin{align*} 2{\rm area}\ ABCD' &=|B-C||C-D'|\sin\ \angle\ BCD' + |A-B| ||A-D'|\sin\ \angle\ BAD'
\\& \geq | B-C||A-D| + |A-B| |C-D| \end{align*}